# PDF viewer : side by side in full screen

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat

I want to use Adobe acrobat reader DC  (version 2020) in which I want 2 pages on the screen like we say: side to side.
These pages would then be displayed in full-screen mode without the menu's so that only the pages are displayed.
Problem =  side to side in fullscreen results in 1 page in full-screen mode :-(

Many thanks in advance for your help.
Johan